# dropdown-content not displaying, even when display is set to block

Tags: html, css

I'm trying to make a dropdown list for my website, but for some reason the dropdown-content div is not shown. I set the display to "block" in my CSS, but it still doesn't show up.

Here is my HTML:

```
<div class = "dropdown">
<li class = "topnavitem"> 
  <a> Projects </a>
  <div class = "dropdown-content">
    <a href="#"> Project 1 </a>
    <a href="#"> Project 2 </a>
    <a href="#"> Project 3 </a>
  </div>
</li>
</div>
```

And here is my CSS:

```
.dropdown {
  display:block;
  float:left;

}

.dropdown-content {
    display: block;
    position: absolute;
    background-color: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.8);
    width: 20%;
}

.dropdown-content a {
    color: white;
    padding: 12px 16px;
    text-decoration: none;
    display: block;
}

li.topnavitem:hover .dropdown-content {
    display: block;
}

li.topnavitem {
float: left;
}

li.topnavitem a {
    display: block;
    color: white;
    text-align: center;
    padding: 14px 16px;
    text-decoration: none;
}

li.topnavitem a:hover {
    background-color:grey;
}
```

I do have more code concerning the actual navbar, but I'm fairly sure the problem is with this code. Thanks in advance.

Comment: it seems it is working fine. i just changed color:black instead of white
https://fiddle.jshell.net/x3L3pu1b/1/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

as i mentioned in my comment, here is a **[working JS Fiddle](https://fiddle.jshell.net/x3L3pu1b/1/)**

I just added **color:black;**

```
li.topnavitem a {
    display: block;
    color: black;
    text-align: center;
    padding: 14px 16px;
    text-decoration: none;
}
```

Is this is what you are looking for?

Answer (score 0):

What I think you want,it's something like that :

```css
.dropdown {
  display:block;
  float:left;

}

.dropdown-content {
    display: none;
    position: absolute;
    background-color: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.8);
    width: 20%;
}

.dropdown-content a {
    color: initial;
    padding: 12px 16px;
    text-decoration: none;
    display: block;
}

.topnavitem:hover .dropdown-content {
    display: block;
}

ul{
list-style-type:none;
}

li.topnavitem {
float: left;
}
li.topnavitem a {
    display: block;
    color: black;
    text-align: center;
    padding: 14px 16px;
    text-decoration: none;
}

.topnavitem a:hover {
    background-color:grey;
}
```

```html
<div class = "dropdown">
<ul class = "topnavitem"> 
  <a> Projects </a>
  <div class = "dropdown-content">
  <li><a href=""> Project 1 </a></li>
  <li><a href=""> Project 2 </a></li>
  <li><a href=""> Project 3 </a></li>
  </div>
</ul>
</div>
```